# Why do coordinates in Bezier curves add to the padding in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I have a little `tikzpicture` drawn with a Bezier curve, that I use in the text. I noticed that it has an unusual amount of horizontal white space, more than e.g. a circle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    Lorem
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (a) at (-1,2);
        \draw (0,0) .. controls (a) and ($2*(a -| 0,0)-(a)$) .. (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    ipsum

    Lorem
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (a) at (-1,2);
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=0.4cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    ipsum
\end{document}
```

I think that the white space comes from the coordinates that are used in the `controls`-syntax of the Bezier curves:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    Lorem
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (a) at (-1,2);
        \draw (0,0) .. controls (a) and ($2*(a -| 0,0)-(a)$) .. (0,0);
        \node[red] at (a)                  {$\cdot$};
        \node[red] at ($2*(a -| 0,0)-(a)$) {$\cdot$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    ipsum
\end{document}
```

But just adding the coordinate to e.g. the circle picture doesn't give that extra white space! What's going on here? How can I avoid that?

Comment: Related but not dupe : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43621/bounding-box-is-larger-than-expected-when-drawing-a-curved-path

Comment: The circle picture doesn't get the extra white space as the the picture's bounding box is only updated when a coordinate is used in a path. It you use `\path (a);` after the coordinate is defined, the bounding box will be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [What type of curve is used by Tikz when I "bend" an edge?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223088/what-type-of-curve-is-used-by-tikz-when-i-bend-an-edge/223095#223095), your example code can be changed to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{
    show control points/.style={
        decoration={show path construction, curveto code={
                \draw [blue, dashed]
                    (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
                    node [at end, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
                \draw [blue, dashed]
                    (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
                    node [at start, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
}
\begin{document}
    Lorem
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (a) at (-1,2);
        \draw[show control points] (0,0) .. controls (a) and ($2*(a -| 0,0)-(a)$) .. (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    ipsum

    Lorem
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (a) at (-1,2);
        \draw[show control points] (0,0) circle [radius=0.4cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    ipsum
\end{document}
```

This shows the Bezier control points which look like this:

[image: Bezier control points]

Note that the bounding box for a TikZ figure includes all of the control points. You can use `\useasboundingbox` to fix this:

```
    Lorem
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (a) at (-1,2);
        \useasboundingbox (-.2,0) rectangle (.2,1.5);
        \draw[show control points] (0,0) .. controls (a) and ($2*(a -| 0,0)-(a)$) .. (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    ipsum
```

which yields:

[image: Changing the bounding box.]

Comment: That's a very beautiful demonstration.