# Tikz picture bounding box when using to[in=xxx, out=yyy]

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

I have this two simple images:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \fbox{\tikz{% 
        \fill[red!20] (0,0) to[in=210,out=30] (10,0) -- (10,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
        }}

    \bigskip

    \fbox{\tikz{% 
        \fill[red!20] (0,0) -- (10,0) -- (10,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
        }}
\end{document}
```

And I am quite surprised about the bounding box of the first one:

[image: Result with wildly different b-b]

Is it possible to achieve (automatically) tighter bounding box when using `to[in=..., out=...]` construct?

Comment: Short answer no. Longer is here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43621/bounding-box-is-larger-than-expected-when-drawing-a-curved-path and here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238395/why-do-coordinates-in-bezier-curves-add-to-the-padding-in-tikz

Comment: @percusse --- thanks. I think it's really a dupe, I was not able to find them...