# Why are there jumping frames when I increase the radius?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why are there jumping frames when I increase the radius `\r` from 1.9 to 1.95 ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1.95}
\foreach \j in {0,10,20,...,110}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
 \draw (-2.2,-2.2) rectangle (2.2,2.2);%
 \draw(0,0) circle (.25);%
 \foreach \i in {0,1,2}{\draw[rotate=\i*120] (\j:\r) arc (\j:90+\j:\r) -- (90+\j:.3) arc (90+\j:\j:.3) -- cycle;}%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\end{document}
```

## `\r=1.95` (wrong)

[image]

## `\r=1.9` (correct)

[image]

Comment: Its a size / dimension problem. A workaround is to use a bigger rectangle`\draw[red] (-2.3,-2.3) rectangle (2.3,2.3); `. Still now i don't know the reason for this behaviour. It also appear with a smaller radius and smaller rectangle (r=1.7, and rectangle =(-2.0,-2.0) to  (2.0,2.0)).

Comment: The dimension problem in this case is counter intuitive. What is wrong with my settings? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Make sure you know how to use `\pgfresetboundingbox` or `\pgfinterruptboundingbox`.

## Playing code

This is basically the example of `show path construction` in the manual. In addition to curves I showed the support points so it can be seen that it is the support points that exceeds the frame.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{2.1}
\tikzset{
    decoration={
        show path construction,
        moveto code={
            \fill[red](\tikzinputsegmentfirst)circle(2pt)
                node[fill=none,below]{moveto};},
        lineto code={
            \draw[blue,->](\tikzinputsegmentfirst)--(\tikzinputsegmentlast)
                node[pos=.5,auto]{lineto};
        },
        curveto code={
            \draw[green!75!black,dashed](\tikzinputsegmentfirst)--(\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
                (\tikzinputsegmentlast)--(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb);
            \draw[green!75!black,->](\tikzinputsegmentfirst)..controls
                (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)and(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
                ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast)node[pos=.5,auto]{curveto};
        },
        closepath code={
            \draw[orange,->](\tikzinputsegmentfirst)--(\tikzinputsegmentlast)
                node[pos=.5,auto]{closepath};
        }
    }
}
\foreach \j in {0,5,...,119}{
    \tikz[scale=3]{
        \draw[line width=1.2](-2.2,-2.2)rectangle(2.2,2.2)(0,0)circle(.25);
        \foreach\i in{0,1,2}{
            \draw[rotate=\i*120,decorate](\j:\r)arc(\j:90+\j:\r)--(90+\j:.3)arc(90+\j:\j:.3)--cycle;
        }% 
    }
}%
\end{document}
```

See also

- [tikz bounding box / cropping: too much space for curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290357/tikz-bounding-box-cropping-too-much-space-for-curves)
- [Bounding box is larger than expected when drawing a curved path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43621/bounding-box-is-larger-than-expected-when-drawing-a-curved-path)
- [Why do coordinates in Bezier curves add to the padding in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238395/why-do-coordinates-in-bezier-curves-add-to-the-padding-in-tikz)
- [What type of curve is used by Tikz when I "bend" an edge?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223088/what-type-of-curve-is-used-by-tikz-when-i-bend-an-edge)

Comment: Could you add the code?

Answer (score 3):

Use a circle of radius \r (plus something) for calculating the bounding box.

`\useasboundingbox` overrides automatic BBox calculation which includes invisible path components, such as control points of curves.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1.95}
\foreach \j in {0,10,20,...,110}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
% \draw (-2.2,-2.2) rectangle (2.2,2.2);%
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) circle (\r+0.01);                   
 \draw(0,0) circle (.25);%
 \foreach \i in {0,1,2}{\draw[rotate=\i*120] (\j:\r) arc (\j:90+\j:\r) -- (90+\j:.3) arc (90+\j:\j:.3) -- cycle;}%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\end{document}
```