# Remove space from new command

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, white-space

There seems to be extra space in my command but I can not find and delete it. Where does this space come from?

I need to use my arrow inside a box.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newsavebox{\arbox}
\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][]{\sbox{\arbox}{\scalebox{#11}[1]{%
            \tikz[line cap=round,scale=1,semithick]\draw[->,>={Stealth[round]}]%
            (0,0) .. controls (0.3,0) and (0.2,0.3) .. (-0.1,0.5);%
    }}%
    \usebox{\arbox}%
}
\newcommand{\test}[1][]{\sbox{\arbox}{\scalebox{#11}[1]{%
            Text%
    }}%
    \usebox{\arbox}%
}
\begin{document}

    \fboxsep0pt
    \fbox\myarrow
    
    \fbox\test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's probably a property of or feature from Bezier curves. For reference: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf .

Comment: Look at the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238400/213149