# Why is there too much white space over my tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I don't think anything should influence the bounding box, but still I get a lot of white space above my `tikzpicture`. No idea how to fix it. Also not sure how to post picture here (other than link).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,347); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 347

%Shape: Square [id:dp3326266826077382] 
\draw   (20,20) -- (300,20) -- (300,300) -- (20,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp6598308172915477] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (20,160) -- (76,160) -- (76,300) -- (20,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp9607631960830196] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (132,20) -- (188,20) -- (188,300) -- (132,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp4913602627234861] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (244,20) -- (300,20) -- (300,160) -- (244,160) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp18637311726481443] 
\draw   (340,20) -- (620,20) -- (620,300) -- (340,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp10879462581888877] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (340,160) -- (396,160) -- (396,300) -- (340,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp042590528044432974] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (452,20) -- (508,20) -- (508,300) -- (452,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp8368133041216019] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (564,20) -- (620,20) -- (620,160) -- (564,160) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp6432556650031391] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (340,230) -- (348,230) -- (348,300) -- (340,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp8501351470086091] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (356,160) -- (364,160) -- (364,300) -- (356,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp024380291880052418] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (372,160) -- (380,160) -- (380,230) -- (372,230) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp8865615238851052] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (388,160) -- (396,160) -- (396,230) -- (388,230) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp0614665698795509] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (596,20) -- (604,20) -- (604,90) -- (596,90) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp11443805463112966] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (580,20) -- (588,20) -- (588,160) -- (580,160) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp750623688120593] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (564,90) -- (572,90) -- (572,160) -- (564,160) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp3613640006001597] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (452,160) -- (460,160) -- (460,300) -- (452,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp071060074357018] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (468,20) -- (476,20) -- (476,300) -- (468,300) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp8403148942291725] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (484,20) -- (492,20) -- (492,160) -- (484,160) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp4948036396612854] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (500,20) -- (508,20) -- (508,160) -- (500,160) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp7751051729261558] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 144; green, 19; blue, 254 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (612,20) -- (620,20) -- (620,90) -- (612,90) -- cycle ;
%Curve Lines [id:da04472292148459256] 
\draw    (48,300.34) .. controls (81.33,332.02) and (119.23,330.04) .. (158.8,300.89) ;
\draw [shift={(160,300)}, rotate = 143.13] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da7471540339883456] 
\draw    (160,300) .. controls (193.5,331.84) and (259.67,276.9) .. (271.82,161.74) ;
\draw [shift={(272,160)}, rotate = 95.73] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da04183912988012217] 
\draw    (344,300) .. controls (377.33,331.68) and (415.23,330.04) .. (454.8,300.89) ;
\draw [shift={(456,300)}, rotate = 143.13] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da5730355962662446] 
\draw    (456,300) .. controls (489.5,331.84) and (551.05,245.22) .. (567.75,161.27) ;
\draw [shift={(568,160)}, rotate = 100.96] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da9917744080887023] 
\draw    (568,90) .. controls (510.33,-67.66) and (383,21.68) .. (360,160) ;
\draw [shift={(360,160)}, rotate = 279.44] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da7864020859986232] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (360,300) .. controls (393.33,331.68) and (431.23,329.7) .. (470.8,300.55) ;
\draw [shift={(472,299.66)}, rotate = 143.13] [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da42830860026959616] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (472,300) .. controls (505.5,331.84) and (567.71,259.08) .. (583.76,161.47) ;
\draw [shift={(584,160)}, rotate = 99.05] [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da7536411477198044] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (584,20) .. controls (478.33,-16.32) and (399,21.68) .. (376,160) ;
\draw [shift={(376,160)}, rotate = 279.44] [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da9293457318034677] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (376,230) .. controls (478.33,358.34) and (487,363.01) .. (488,160) ;
\draw [shift={(488,160)}, rotate = 90.28] [color={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da31395724084484544] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (488,160) .. controls (599.77,205.45) and (595.05,176.64) .. (599.93,91.29) ;
\draw [shift={(600,90)}, rotate = 93.31] [color={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da435351615237183] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (600,20) .. controls (494.33,-16.32) and (415,21.68) .. (392,160) ;
\draw [shift={(392,160)}, rotate = 279.44] [color={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da46919834214932754] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (392,230) .. controls (494.33,358.34) and (503,363.01) .. (504,160) ;
\draw [shift={(504,160)}, rotate = 90.28] [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da8428496850662717] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (504,160) .. controls (615.77,205.45) and (611.05,176.64) .. (615.93,91.29) ;
\draw [shift={(616,90)}, rotate = 93.31] [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

% Text Node
\draw (152,313.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$f_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (472,323.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$f_{2}$};
% Text Node
\draw (38.67,168.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$A_{0}$};
% Text Node
\draw (258.67,28.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$A_{2}$};
% Text Node
\draw (147.33,28.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$A_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (312.67,256.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{00}$};
% Text Node
\draw (398,198.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{03}$};
% Text Node
\draw (364,241.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{02}$};
% Text Node
\draw (334.67,185.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{01}$};
% Text Node
\draw (509.33,95.07) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{13}$};
% Text Node
\draw (478,169.07) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{12}$};
% Text Node
\draw (444.67,114.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{11}$};
% Text Node
\draw (428,237.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{10}$};
% Text Node
\draw (621.33,53.07) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{23}$};
% Text Node
\draw (590,99.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{22}$};
% Text Node
\draw (552,55.07) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{21}$};
% Text Node
\draw (537.33,118.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\footnotesize]  {$A_{20}$};

\node at (336,360,1) {\textit{Fig. 6}};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Guess: Use \centering instead of the center environment. {\centering Tikz code}.

Comment: The center environment adds vertical white space AFAIK

Comment: it's the same even when using centering or even without any of them :(

Comment: actually not the same, but the difference is very small - still a lot of space over the picture

Comment: I am sure this has been asked many times - the control points enlarges the bounding box. You need to set it manually.

Comment: `\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (5,5);` - with suitable coordinates

Comment: The code looks to be generated by some automated software, is that so?

Comment: Yes. It was generated by mathcha.io

Comment: To add an image, there is an icon at the top of the question box.  Click it, and a link for the image will be added in the place where your cursor is located in the box.  (I just tried to do that and the proper code was entered, but it was shown as the input instruction, not the image itself; I don't understand why, and have retracted the edit.)

Comment: @hpekristiansen it helped, thank you! Please write it as an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Apparently it had something to do with the way OP's code was entered (I have never understood how some enter block code not with the button(make four space indentation) but with some `````

Comment: @hpekristiansen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290357/tikz-bounding-box-cropping-too-much-space-for-curves?

Comment: @hpekristiansen -- I've just entered a [question in meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8911) asking for an explanation.  Presumably you managed to add the correct link, in which case thanks.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278979/whitespace-around-tikz-automaton/543239#543239 by the way.