# Too much space between `figure`-`tikzpicture` and `caption`

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

Too much space between `figure`-`tikzpicture` and `caption`. Also, `\centering` doesn't seem to be working properly, as it places the figure far to the left.

It's as if the `tikz` drawing is larger than it actually shows, having white space both to the left and below.

[image: actual result]

The expected result is to maintain a normal center and without extra space that breaks with the aesthetics of the document, something like:

[image: spected result]

Is there something I'm missing to make this happen? Can I put a frame on the figure and/or the `tikz` picture to see the space they occupy?

The code I'm trying to implement is as follows:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
La variable de tipo puntero se utilizan para almacenar en ellas la dirección de memoria de otra variable. El puntero, como variable que es tiene asociado su dirección de memoria y su contenido será la dirección de memoria de otra variable (véase figura \ref{puntero}).

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-] (0,0) -- (7.5,0) 
            node at (1.5,0.5) {DIR MEM} 
            node at (4,0.5) {VAR}
            node at (6,0.5) {VALOR};
        \draw[-] (3,0) -- (3,-1.9) 
            node at (1.5,-0.5) {0xFFFFFFF0} 
            node at (4,-0.5) {\textit{num1}} 
            node at (6,-0.5) {5} 
            node at (1.5,-1) {0xFFFFFFF1}
            node at (4,-1) {\textit{punt}} 
            node at (6.3,-1) {0xFFFFFFF0} 
            node at (1.5,-1.5) {0xFFFFFFF2};
        \draw[-stealth,gray] (6.3,-1.3) to[out=300, in=180] (0.2,-0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Ejemplo de puntero \textit{punt} que referenciua a la dirección de memoria 0xFFFFFFF0 que es, a su vez, la variable entera \textit{num1} que almacena el valor 5.}
    \label{puntero}
\end{figure}

Los punteros pueden apuntar a variables previamente declaradas o a variables dinámicas.La potencia de los punteros reside en poder crear (reservar memoria) y destruir (liberar memoria) una variable (dinámica) en tiempo de ejecución.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a TeX.SE!!!. You probably need `\useasboundingbox` (Ti*k*Z manual v3.19a, p.172,184), but it's difficult to say without a MWE. See: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: If you use the `overlay` option, the tikz picture won't influence the spacing. Please add a minimal working example which shows the code you use.

Comment: Added code block, I don't understand how I could have forgotten it, sorry!

Comment: @FcoJavierBalón Try with `\draw[-stealth,gray,overlay] (6.3,-1.3) to[out=300, in=180] (0.2,-0.5);`

Comment: And please don't post code fragments. Always make a compilable minimal working example. Things like guessing the necessary packages etc. get boring very fast ...

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543239/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `overlay` option to make sure that your arrow does not influence the size of the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
La variable de tipo puntero se utilizan para almacenar en ellas la dirección de memoria de otra variable. El puntero, como variable que es tiene asociado su dirección de memoria y su contenido será la dirección de memoria de otra variable (véase figura \ref{puntero}).

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-] (0,0) -- (7.5,0) 
            node at (1.5,0.5) {DIR MEM} 
            node at (4,0.5) {VAR}
            node at (6,0.5) {VALOR};
        \draw[-] (3,0) -- (3,-1.9) 
            node at (1.5,-0.5) {0xFFFFFFF0} 
            node at (4,-0.5) {\textit{num1}} 
            node at (6,-0.5) {5} 
            node at (1.5,-1) {0xFFFFFFF1}
            node at (4,-1) {\textit{punt}} 
            node at (6.3,-1) {0xFFFFFFF0} 
            node at (1.5,-1.5) {0xFFFFFFF2};
        \draw[-stealth,gray,overlay] (6.3,-1.3) to[out=300, in=180] (0.2,-0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Ejemplo de puntero \textit{punt} que referenciua a la dirección de memoria 0xFFFFFFF0 que es, a su vez, la variable entera \textit{num1} que almacena el valor 5.}
    \label{puntero}
\end{figure}

Los punteros pueden apuntar a variables previamente declaradas o a variables dinámicas.La potencia de los punteros reside en poder crear (reservar memoria) y destruir (liberar memoria) una variable (dinámica) en tiempo de ejecución.
\end{document}
```

[image]