# Trying to draw a picture of an automata in TexMaker using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

[image: Picture of the automaton]I'm looking for some help drawing automata in TexMaker. My problem is that the lines of the automata cross and it makes the whole thing a bit unreadable.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2.5cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial] (0) {$q_0$};
   \node[state] (1) [right=of 0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state, accepting] (2) [right=of 1] {$q_2$};
   \node[state, accepting] (3) [right=of 2] {$q_3$};
   \node[state] (4) [right=of 3] {$q_4$};
   \path[->]
    (0) edge [bend left]    node {$a$} (2)
    (0) edge [loop below]   node {$b$} (0)
    (0) edge                node {$c$} (1)
    (1) edge                node {$a$} (2)
    (1) edge [bend left]    node {$b$} (4)
    (1) edge [loop below]   node {$c$} (1)
    (2) edge [bend right]   node {$a$} (0)
    (2) edge [loop below]   node {$b$} (2)
    (2) edge                node {$c$} (3)
    (3) edge [bend right]   node {$a$} (0)
    (3) edge                node {$b$} (4)
    (3) edge [loop below]   node {$c$} (3)
    (4) edge [loop below]   node {$a$, $b$, $c$} (4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please copy the code into the question, don't use an external hosting cite.

Comment: The bend options can take a value that controls how bent they are. This way you can manually avoid overlapping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bend options can take a value that controls how bent they are.
This way you can manually avoid overlapping.
In this case you can make the edges pointing to `(0)` go below the states and to avoid clash with the loops they can be bent at a `60` degrees angle with `bend left=60`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2.5cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial] (0) {$q_0$};
   \node[state] (1) [right=of 0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state, accepting] (2) [right=of 1] {$q_2$};
   \node[state, accepting] (3) [right=of 2] {$q_3$};
   \node[state] (4) [right=of 3] {$q_4$};
   \path[->]
    (0) edge [bend left]    node {$a$} (2)
    (0) edge [loop below]   node {$b$} (0)
    (0) edge                node {$c$} (1)
    (1) edge                node {$a$} (2)
    (1) edge [bend left]    node {$b$} (4)
    (1) edge [loop below]   node {$c$} (1)
    (2) edge [bend left=60]   node {$a$} (0)
    (2) edge [loop below]   node {$b$} (2)
    (2) edge                node {$c$} (3)
    (3) edge [bend left=60]   node {$a$} (0)
    (3) edge                node {$b$} (4)
    (3) edge [loop below]   node {$c$} (3)
    (4) edge [loop below]   node {$a$, $b$, $c$} (4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: better]

Comment: Thank you for your speedy answer. I'll experiment a bit with the angling of the bend left/right command.

Comment: @Carst if you want to know more about the bend param, here I explain how the parameters work and how to visualise them in the picture http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223095/36686