# Draw the following paths

Tags: diagrams

I want to draw the following paths. But I don't know how to start because I am new to this and I am learning. Can someone help me?[image]

Comment: Hi I think it is good example to start  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279221/trying-to-draw-a-picture-of-an-automata-in-texmaker-using-tikz

Answer (score 5):

With use of the `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm,
  start chain = v going right,
     V/.style = {circle,draw, fill=blue, inner sep=1pt, 
            node contents={}, on chain},
every label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize\sffamily, text=blue}
                    ]
\foreach \x in {A, B, C, D}
    \node[V, label=\x];
%
\draw (v-1) to (v-2) 
      (v-1) to [bend left]  (v-2)
      (v-1) to [bend left=45]   (v-3)
      (v-1) to [bend right] (v-2)
      (v-1) to [bend right=45]  (v-2)
      (v-1) to [bend right=45]  (v-3)
      (v-2) to [bend left]  (v-3)
      (v-2) to [bend right] (v-3)
      (v-3) to [bend left]  (v-4)
      (v-3) to (v-4)
      (v-3) to [bend right] (v-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.5)(10,1.5)
\sffamily\color{Blue} \psset{PtNameMath=false}
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={120,90,90,60}](0,0){A}(3,0){B}(6,0){C}(9,0){D}
\psline(A)(B) \psline(C)(D)
\pcarc[arcangle=40](A)(B)\pcarc[arcangle=60](B)(C)      \pcarc[arcangle=40](C)(D)
\pcarc[arcangle=-30](A)(B)\pcarc[arcangle=-30](B)(C)  \pcarc[arcangle=-30](C)(D)
\pcarc[arcangle=60](A)(C)\pcarc[arcangle=-60](A)(C)
\pcarc[arcangle=-60](A)(B)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have problems when I compiled it.

Comment: @AlejandraBenítez What are the problems? If you use a basic distribuition of MikTeX (for example) peraphs the package pst-eucl it is not into.

Comment: @Sebastiano I used TexStudio and already installed the package but I always have errors

Comment: @AlejandraBenítez: If you compile with  `pdflatex`, it doesn't work because pdflatex doesn't have the tools to make the computations required by Adobe Postscript code. So either, you follow the traditional chain: `latex > dvips > pstopdf`, or, simpler, you compile with `xelatex --shell-escape`.