# TikZ Curved Path Construction, Controls is not mathematically unique

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the TikZ & PGF Manual for Version 3.1.5b, page 33/1318, section 2.4, we get Curved Path Construction. The general syntax for extending a path in a “curved” way is
.. controls  and  .. .

This curve mathematically is not unique. I like to read the source code for this to understand how exactly they define this controls curve. There are many curves that can be a solution. Do you know where I can get the source code?

Comment: It's a Bézier curve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223088/what-type-of-curve-is-used-by-tikz-when-i-bend-an-edge/223095 The syntax referred to in that question is e.g. `\draw (0,0) to[bend left] (1,0) to[bend right=30] (2,0);`.